# SQL for Opening Hours

Tags: sql, database, schema

In my shops database I need to have the opening hours. Do you have an idea how i can implement this in my dB?

The opening hours are from Monday to Sunday, each day can have 2 opening windows (ex 09:00-12:00, 16:00-19:00)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

build another table, call it `schedules`, add a foreign key to the `shops` table primary key, a `Day of week` field, `time_open`, `time_closed`.
The data should look something like this:

```
shop_id     day_of_week      time_open        time_closed
1           1                09:00            12:00
1           1                16:00            19:00
1           2                09:00            12:00
1           2                16:00            19:00
1           3                09:00            12:00
1           3                16:00            19:00
1           6                10:00            14:00
2           1                09:00            12:00
2           1                13:00            18:00
```

This will give you the opportunity to build any kind of schedules, with as many windows as you want, with how many exceptions you need. It's universal, limited only to the fact that it expects all weeks to be identical. No holidays considered, nor odd/even-week schedules that someone might use.

**Edit:**
With Julien's question, about working hours of a night business, it has come to my attention that the previous solution is not the best bu far. You can't have a bar open at 20:00, close at 06:00, and compare if current time (02:45) is inside this interval, because it won't be. That's why, it would be most convenient to register not the closing time, but the total working time, in the convenient unit of measure (minutes for example).

```
shop_id     day_of_week      time_open        working_time
1           1                09:00            180
1           1                16:00            180
1           2                09:00            180
1           2                16:00            180
1           3                09:00            180
1           3                16:00            180
1           6                10:00            240
2           1                09:00            180
2           1                13:00            300
```

Comment: this will allow you to add a third schedule for a given day, if that's a violation of your rules, you'll need to tightly control the addition of new schedules to check for that... or you could add a "sched_num" column with a check constraint that it be either a 0 or 1 and a unique constraint on day_of_week and sched_num.

Comment: which is the better way for handling opening hours for night biz, like a bar, open from 10:00pm to 04:00am. Add two entry (day1 : 22:00->23:59 and day2: 00:00->04:00) ? or one entry (day1: 22:00->04:00) ?

Comment: Interesting question. In this case it would be most reasonable to re-make this situation. See edited response.

Comment: I think in this situation, I would just record the time in decimal hours and allow > 24 hours in a day. So, on Saturday, the bar might be open from 22.00 to 28.00 (4am the next day). For example. But it really depends on the use cases I'd be supporting with the database.

Comment: I was thinking...for the second open/close window  why not add two more columns...so for open/close in total 4 columns...open_a,close_a,open_b,close_b....just a thought

Comment: Because that would denormalize the data. Never add columns that look like they enumerate something. This is bad design and something that should've been a row. It's harder to query such tables, and they limit you to a max number of things that are enumerated. In your case a,b. I've had to work with tables that ended up with 10 such columns for a single name, and I started contemplating about stalking the author and putting a bloody horse head in his bed while he's sleeping. Jokes aside, don't do it please :)

Answer (score 5):

What type of database are you using?  If it's mysql, put in a field of type "time".  Then you can pass it the times and do basic sql time manipulations on them.  This whole post assumes mysql.

If there is only one store and you know it will never grow, just make a table called times where you keep the times the store is open.  Then, if you want to see if the store is open just check the current time against one of the ranges in the database.

If there is more than one store, make a table called "times" and a table called "stores".    In the times table, columns can be "open" and "close" with an id called "store_id".  The stores table needs an id too.  Then, you can just say:

```
"SELECT open, close FROM times WHERE store_id=x"
```

This will give you ALL the time ranges associated with the particular store.