# find if current time falls between multiple time ranges

Tags: c#, datetime, range, timespan

I am trying to show open or closed status for store based on time range stored in database.

Each store can have 2 opening hours

Example:

09:00 AM to to 11:00 AM and 01:00 PM to 10:00 PM

**Works for single time range :**

```
IEnumerable<Timings> timings = allStore.ToList(); // from database

foreach (var storetime in timings)
{
TimeSpan openSpan = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)storetime.OpenTime);

TimeSpan openLocalTime = TimeConversions.UTCTimeToLocalTime(openSpan);

DateTime openDatetime = DateTime.Today.Add(openLocalTime);

string openDisplayTime = openDatetime.ToString("hh:mm tt");

.....

TimeSpan closeLocalTime = TimeConversions.UTCTimeToLocalTime(closeSpan);

if ((now > openLocalTime) && (now < closeLocalTime))
{                        
 //Store is Open          
}

else 
{
//Store is Closed  
}

}
```

**Multiple Ranges:**

```
 IEnumerable<Timings> timings = allStore.ToList(); // from database

 if((timings.Any(now > d=>d.OpenTime)))  // can i use Any ?
 {

 }
```

Here is [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721533/sql-for-opening-hours) structure.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Does the solution have to be in C#? IMO it would be better to write it directly in SQL instead of retrieving all the opening times.

Comment: I don't understand your code. Why is `openLocalTime` a `Timespan` and not a `DateTime` (same goes for close time). What is `TimeConversions.UTCTimeToLocalTime` and what object type is `Timings`?

Comment: @Philippe, i just use the ticks as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504020/2218697) i have stored ticks in database as 'BigInt' and `TimeConversions.UTCTimeToLocalTime` is used to get convert UTC ticks to local timespan , timings is list of timings for each  store, i have updated the post . hope that helps.

Comment: @Stom To represent opening times you can either have a start time (`DateTime`) when the store opens and say for how long it is open by using a `Timespan` or have a start and end time (`DateTime`). As a `Timespan` represents a duration and has no notion of when it starts, I think `openSpan` should be a `DateTime` containing the hours and minutes and should not be a `Timespan`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Any`, since you only need the current time to be within an open range *once*.

```
IEnumerable<Timings> timings = allStore.ToList(); // from database

if(timings.Any(d => (now >= d.OpenTime) && (now <= d.CloseTime)))
{

}
```

As @martin suggested, executing this query on the database might be a better solution. I don't know what your database looks like, but the query would be something like this:

```
bool isOpen = db.Stores
    .Single(s => s.Id = whatever)
    .OpeningHours.Any(d => (now >= d.OpenTime) && (now <= d.CloseTime));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding , i have stored ticks in database as 'BigInt', i get this error when i use your first method: `Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'long?''` i have updated the post.

Comment: Then you should convert now to a DateTime (has a constructor or static method that takes ticks I think) and compare only the Time part. Unless the Opening hours can be over midnight, that would be a bit more complicated.