# Suggestions for Modeling Operating Hours

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I need to model a table, and relationship that represents the following:
The hours of operation of a company.

My initial idea is, `1 Company - N business hours.`
That's because depending on the day, the timetable may vary. Example: On Saturdays the company works until 12:00 PM. And from Monday to Friday, it works until 6:00 PM. Do you understand? These are things that vary and I need to have this in a table.

It's confusing for me, what fields do I put to answer the following question: Which companies are open now?

My database is mysql

Comment: So it seems like you need a day column too!?!

Comment: Please show us some sample data.  I think your question is too vague as it stands right now.

Comment: I can not go on. You do not have to worry about the table, and how it can be queried.

Comment: In the end I need to do a search on the companies that are open.
But I do not know how to put them together for this kind of problem.

Comment: One of my most popular answers for some reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721533/sql-for-opening-hours/2721596#2721596 . Have you tried searching before posting? Using this, adding a column for the company ID, and doing basic time operations in a query will yield you the results needed.

Comment: Related, but for Postgres: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/perform-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524